# VS 2010 setup customization languege

Tags: localization, outlook-addin

I'm realizing a custom setup for my outlook addin. I want the installer in Dutch language, but VS 2010 doesn't support this language.

Is there a solution to my issue?

Answer (score 1):

The default procedure to make a dutch language msi setup is to use orca.exe on the msi file and translate the TEXT column of some tables. (you can also do this by extracting the msi database and by importing it back in the msi when the translation has been done).
But there is the other way: Creating the language support directly in the Setup project creator.
I'm using VS.NET 2003 (yeps still the old version) and when you create a setup project you have no dutch language support in the project localisation.  I figured out how that thing works but I'm stuck in the language change of the msiloadr.bin and the webloadr.bin files (both dll files included in the distribution) (step 3 in the comment below). The unusual procedure to include directly the language support in the VS.Net Setup project :
1) get the local identifier and the code page for your language (http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/intl/nls_238z.asp)
2) Go to the VS.NET/Common7/Tools/Deployment/VsdDialogs directory and copy 1033 (english) directory to 1043 directory (dutch). Translate all the files in that directory with orca.exe and update the 1033 language code to 1043
3) Go to the VS.NET/Common7/Tools/Deployment/MsiRedist directory and copy 1033 (english) directory to 1043 directory (dutch). Here we need to update the bin files (DLL) to set it up as a dutch language.
4) Update the registry (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\7.1\Deployment\DialogTemplates:) 
Append ", Dutch" to the Languages key
Append ", 1043" to the Identifiers key
Append ", 1252" to the CodePages key
Once you have done that you'll be able to compile any Setup project in the dutch language and this can be done for all the missing languages. (If you solve the 3rd step)
Maybe you have some solution to solve for the unofficial sulution by tweaking VS.NET :-)

Copied from: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/2d062f34-5615-47c8-aa7b-a69fbd68e983/how-to-make-a-installer-in-dutch-language

Answer (score 0):

Please read this :-

[Set up creation using selected language](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/fe8b14cb-3967-4d05-a167-7d563d8ceaf5/setup-project-change-language?forum=winformssetup)